# Estimating default probability if no default in history

Tags: default-probability, macro, logit

I would like to estimate a given country's default probability with a logit regression from macro variables but there was no default in it's history. I was able to calculate the probabilities of downgrade (credit migration risk) though but I don't know how to calculate the default probabilities from the credit downgrade probabilities.

Can you please help what can I use instead?

Comment: Which country is it? Are you able to assume similarities to another country?

Comment: The current credit rating provides a (rough) estimate of PD, based on the historical experience of all countries that have had that rating. If in addition you have information that the credit rating could stay the same, go up 1 notch with some prob and go down 1 notch with some prob, then you could average together the PD's associated with the 3 prospective credit ratings, using the probs as weights. It seems complicated and I don't know if anyone does it this way.

Comment: so say to use cross sectional data instead of time series. Good idea thank you